# Connection fails: Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-undefined" for connection type "undefined"

Tags: rest, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to set up a persistent REST Server on the pre-release version of composer - 0.17.1. However, when I look at the docker logs of my REST server I get the following error:

```
Connection fails: Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-undefined" for connection type "undefined".
```

I think this is an environment dependency issue. I used the following commands to update my environment to the v0.17.1 release:

```
npm install -g composer-cli@next

npm install -g composer-rest-server@next

npm install -g generator-hyperledger-composer@next
```

Or it could be a problem with my package.json file. I have been looking for a sample package.json file to work with the pre-release version but haven't been able to find one.

My package.json file:

```
    {
  "engines": {
    "composer": "^0.17.1"
  },
  "name": "block-network",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Business Network",
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "postlicchk": "npm run doc",
    "doc": "jsdoc --pedantic --recurse -c jsdoc.json",
    "test": "mocha -t 0 --recursive",
    "deploy": "./scripts/deploy.sh"
  },
  "author": "Simon Mullaney",
  "email": "",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserfs": "^1.2.0",
    "chai": "latest",
    "composer-common": "^0.17.1",
    "composer-playground-api": "^0.17.1",
    "composer-admin": "^0.17.1",
    "composer-client": "^0.17.1",
    "composer-connector-embedded": "^0.17.1",
    "composer-connector-hlfv1": "^0.17.1",
    "composer-connector-proxy": "^0.17.1",
    "composer-connector-server": "^0.17.1",
    "composer-runtime-embedded": "^0.17.1",
    "composer-connector-web": "^0.17.1",
    "composer-runtime": "^0.17.1",
    "composer-runtime-web": "^0.17.1",
    "eslint": "latest",
    "istanbul": "latest",
    "jsdoc": "latest",
    "mkdirp": "latest",
    "mocha": "latest",
    "moment": "latest",
    "sinon": "latest"
  },
  "license-check-config": {
    "src": [
      "**/*.js",
      "!./coverage/**/*",
      "!./node_modules/**/*",
      "!./out/**/*",
      "!./scripts/**/*"
    ],
    "path": "header.txt",
    "blocking": true,
    "logInfo": false,
    "logError": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "latest",
    "opentracing": "^0.14.1",
    "passport-github": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem? Or where I could find a sample network built on V 0.17.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for me was that I was extending from the wrong docker image in my docker file. I needed to add the tag for the v0.17.1 release:

Old docker file:

```
    FROM hyperledger/composer-rest-server
RUN npm install --production loopback-connector-mongodb passport-github && \
    npm cache clean --force && \
    ln -s node_modules .node_modules
```

New docker file:

```
    FROM hyperledger/composer-rest-server:0.17.1
RUN npm install --production loopback-connector-mongodb passport-github && \
    npm cache clean --force && \
    ln -s node_modules .node_modules
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error and resolved according to the below remediation, effectively resetting the node Composer REST-API task-runner:

1. `cd ~/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/`
2. `npm uninstall -g composer-cli`
3. `nvm install --lts`
4. `nvm use --lts`
5. `npm install -g composer-cli`

After the above, compile your .bna file and proceed executables.

Answer (score 1):

There are breaking changes between v0.16.* and v0.17.* - particularly with the connection profiles.

Some checks and information that should help:

- hopefully you ran `npm uninstall -g composer-cli` (and for composer-rest-server) before the installs
- check your composer version with `composer -v` and `npm ls -g --depth=0`
- v0.17.* required Hyperledger Fabric v1.1.0-preview (v0.16.* required v1.0.4)  the command `docker images` will show you the version of Fabric that you are using.

If you are still using Fabric 1.0.4 run these commands from the `fabric-tools` folder:

```
./teardownFabric.sh
export FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv11
./download.sh
./startFabric.sh
```

- the Business Network Cards (specifically the connection.json) are not compatible between v0.16 and v0.17.  I would export any existing cards to .card archive files incase you want the crypto material at a later date - then delete the cards using `composer card delete` and remove the complete `~/.composer` folder.
- assuming you are running the Development Fabric - run `./startFabric.sh` and `./createPeerAdminCard.sh`

You should now be able to deploy your network and run the rest server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RThatcher - I figured out my problem - I just was extending from the wrong composer-rest-server image in my Dockerfile so I needed to add the tag for the v0.17.1 release and it all worked as expected.
Thanks again!